# How to place json file in amp playground

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to use amp playground to replicate my issue in google amp page which I am developing right now. How can I place my own json file in amp playground to replicate the scenario in playground.
https://playground.amp.dev

Comment: Are you trying to link it via `amp-list` ?

Comment: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/

Comment: Yes, I am using amp-list

Comment: @rajashreeraajee https://jsonblob.com/ hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

To test JSON via `amp-list` in the AMP Playground, you need to enable CORS protection. Follow these steps:

1. Make sure the JSON is fetched from a server you have a control over
2. Enable CORS for the AMP Playground with the code below:

```
header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: https://playground.amp.dev"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://playground.amp.dev");
```

NOTE: This is a PHP code, if you are spitting out JSON via some other server side programming language, use their version of the above code, or if it is a `.json` file itself, enable CORS via the server.

[CORS in AMP](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-caches-and-cors/amp-cors-requests/)